# Where is the documentation for New-CMSoftwareUpdateDeploymentPackage

Tags: powershell, system-center

I've been googling and searching MS's website for their MSDN or technet page on this cmdlet and can't find it.  Google keeps wanting to point to the Get cmdlet.  I used the MS link for the Get:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sccm/configurationmanager/vlatest/get-cmsoftwareupdatedeploymentpackage

And tried to use:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sccm/configurationmanager/vlatest/new-cmsoftwareupdatedeploymentpackage

But it fails.  The cmdlet shows up in the ConfigurationModule and because of where the server lives I can't use Update-Help.  There's also no "link" section in the help to point to a technet article.

Anyone know where the MS documentation is on this?

Answer (score 0):

I totally understand your concern. and we're very sorry for any inconvenience that may caused. we will also report this issue.

You could use the following command to get the syntax at the moment:

Get-Help New-CMSoftwareUpdateDeploymentPackage -Full

[Here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/New-CMSoftwareUpdateDeploym-4cf3c878) are some very good information and hints for your reference.